# repetitive values

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, histogram, pie-chart

I have a data table that looks like this:

```
USER    AREA
1   X723
1   X278
2   X827
2   X567
2   X234
3   X735
3   X673
3   X346
4   X723
5   X678
```

Then I converted the table into:

```
USER    ALL
1   2
2   3
3   3
4   1
5   1
```

My problem is that I have hundreds of thousands of rows (users) and using histogram or pie chart to summarise or explore the data is out of the question because of the large number of observations. I'm trying to understand the areas allocated to each user. Can anyone suggest other ways for me to explore this kind of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your user identifiers are not inherently informative; even if they are, the problem as you say is that you can't show them visually any way.

A common set-up in ecology is to count the numbers of individuals of several species and then further to reduce to the numbers of species with so many individuals. Your data reduce further to

```
#areas #individuals 
1      2 
2      1
3      1
```

and I would look at that distribution. I've clearly no idea how your data behave beyond your example, but log scale for one or both variables might help if either quantity extends over two or more orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments and advice. @Nick Cox I found your suggestion very useful and so have implemented the solution in a similar fashion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use insights from panel data and calculate within (over time) and between (across individuals) standard deviation for the area (I am assuming it is a numeric variable). If you are using Stata, you would first generate a pseudo variable for time-period, then `xtset` the data and finally use `xtsum`:

```
bys USER: gen t = _n
xtset USER t
xtsum AREA
```

Comment: For this to make sense beyond Stata users, I think you need to explain what `xtsum` does, not ask people to read its manual entry. Supporting references are excellent; answers that pivot on most people needing to  read an external source to understand them are not so excellent. (No one knowing the facts could accuse me of hostility to Stata....)

Comment: In my defense, the manual entry was very short :)

Comment: A separate point is that `AREA` appears just to be some identifier and the OP apparently wishes to calculate the number of areas.